# Storm Runtime Files

Tags: java, apache-storm

I have a storm topology running in local mode on a Unix host. When I start it up I noticed it begins filling up the /tmp directory with folders named:

eff9e9fd-4cd6-45fd-ac4e-f6705df65485

Would someone be able to advise what these are and is it possible to disable these (is there a flag that can be set in the code or config file)?

If I'm running my topology for a long period of time my /tmp directory eventually reaches 100% due to the presence of these files, they can be quite large.

Comment: I've not experienced this problem in the past, so this is possibly something specific to the design of your topology.

Comment: Taking another look at this I think the folders are only being created when I run Storm in local cluster mode. If I try to shutdown the cluster I get an IO exception on windows i.e. it cannot remove the folder from the temp directory. Inevitably this means my Temp directory grows quite large (I just cleaned up 15GB of files manually).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation it looks like this issue is isolated to Windows only. I deployed my code base to a Unix host and I was able to run killTopology() and shutdown() which cleaned up the log files automatically.